# python: remove quotes from string to execute as a command or map a string value to key

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, ordereddictionary

```
sqlCur.execute('SELECT TOP 10 '+fld+cc.joins+cc.where,custo)
tub=sqlCur.fetchall()
```

From the above query, I get data from SQL Server to Python tuples. I am converting this data into list of `OrderedDict()` and then use `insert_many` available in `pymongo` to push data to mongodb.
To map SQL columns with mongo columns, I have a `OrderedDict(cols)` which is use as below.

```
sqlCol=list(cols.keys())
mongoCol=list(cols.values())

insArray=[]
for b in tub:
    doc=OrderedDict()
    lst=['b.'+x for x in sqlCol]
    for v in range(len(mongoCol)):
        ii=lst[v]
        doc[ll[v]]=lst[v]
    insArray.append(doc)
```

But, in the result I see the **column names** instead of **values** because the list `lst` is having the **column names** as string but it needs to be mapped with the mongoColumns without **quotes**. 
How do I achieve this or Is there any better way to handle this?
 Btw, I'm using in **Python 3.6**

Comment: Can you share the sample data which one sqlCur returns

Comment: @GThamizh : I get it has a list of tuples like [('GoDad', 73399, 'C'), ('GoDad', 73483, 'I')]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, consider mongo_cols for columns for mongo db collection (It was sample, you can change it with your own mongo db collection schema)

```
mongo_cols = ("name","id","status")

values = [("GoDad", 73399, "C"), ("GoDad", 73483, "I")]

keys_values_insert =[dict(zip(mongo_cols, k)) for k in values]

print (keys_values_insert) # [{'status': 'C', 'name': 'GoDad', 'id': 73399}, {'status': 'I', 'name': 'GoDad', 'id': 73483}]
```

Mongo DB - Process

```
> db.products.insert([{'status': 'C', 'name': 'GoDad', 'id': 73399}, {'status': 'I', 'name': 'GoDad', 'id': 73483}])
> 
>  
> db.products.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5967be93162ab4d87801d2ea"), "status" : "C", "name" : "GoDad", "id" : 73399 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5967be93162ab4d87801d2eb"), "status" : "I", "name" : "GoDad", "id" : 73483 }
```